# Disable didSelectRowAtIndexPath on Long press gesture on Tableview Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I have been trying to setup a long press gesture recognizer on UITableView. The gesture is working fine, but i want to disable the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate function of UITableView when Long Press gesture is recognised.

In short, if user single tap on the cell i have to push a new UIViewController, and if user long press on the cell i have to show an UIActionSheet.

```
extension GroupChatListingViewController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func setupLongPress() {

    longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress))
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0 // 1 second press
    longPressGesture.delegate = self
    longPressGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
}

func longPress(longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {

        self.tableView.allowsSelection = false
        let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.tableView)
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
            self.showActionSheet()
        }
    }
    else if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
        self.tableView.allowsSelection = true
    }
} }
```

Comment: Add tap gesture on tableview cell then it will disable didSelect of tableview

Comment: add tap gesture for single tap and do what you want on tap..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@optimus comment helped me to solve this problem, this is a very genuine situation of disabling didSelectRowAtIndexPath when long press gesture is recognised on the tableview cell which has not been answered on the Internet

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupLongPress()
    setupTapPress()
}

extension GroupChatListingViewController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func setupLongPress() {

    longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress))
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0 // 1 second press
    longPressGesture.delegate = self
    longPressGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
}

func setupTapPress() {

    singlePressGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapPress))
    singlePressGesture.delegate = self
    singlePressGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(singlePressGesture)
}

func tapPress(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if gesture.state == .ended {
        let touchPoint = gesture.location(in: self.tableView)
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
            // do your task on single tap
        }
    }
}

func longPress(longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {

        let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.tableView)
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
            self.showActionSheet()
        }
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This!

```
func longPress(longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {

        self.tableView.allowsSelection = false
        let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.tableView)
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
            self.showActionSheet()
        }
    }
    else if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
        //self.tableView.allowsSelection = true
    }
}
```

Add this override method

```
override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool,
                          completion: (() -> Void)?)
    {
        super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion:completion)

        self.tableView.allowsSelection = true
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Mr.Bean did you check dismiss is called or not with breakpoint. And make sure your code is commented in gesture end state